# Getting overlapping strings from two Lists of different classes

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

Say I have two different classes:

```
class Animal
{
    string Name {get; set;}
    int Age {get; set;}
    string Description {get; set;}
}

class ButcheringMemo
{
    string ButcherShopName {get; set;}
    DateTime ButcheringTime {get; set;}
    string AnimalName {get; set;}
}
```

If I were to have a list of Animal and a list of ButcheringMemo, what would be the best way of creating a product list of Animal where Name from Animal appears as AnimalName in ButcheringMemo?

My sloppy way is as follows:

```
List<Animal> animalsToButcher = new List<Animal>();
List<ButcheringMemo> butcheringMemos = getAllButcheringMemos();
List<string> animalNamesInButchering = new List<string>();

foreach (ButcheringMemo memo in butcheringMemos)
{
   animalNamesInButchering.Add(memo.AnimalName);
}

List<Animal> animals = getAllAnimals();

foreach (Animal animal in animals)
{
   bool isIn = false;
   foreach (string name in animalNamesInButchering)
   {
      if (animal.Name == name)
         isIn = true;
   }

   if (!isIn)
   {
      animalsToButcher.Add(animal);
   }
}

return animalsToButcher;
```

I feel like there's got to be a better way than to have a for loop within a for loop.

Comment: You might want to post on our sister site [CodeReview.SE] for feedback on working code.

Comment: `List<string> animalNamesInButchering = butcheringMemos.Select(b => b.AnimalName).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ, you can combine it all into one statement:

```
animalsToButcher = animals.Where(a => butcheringMemos.Select(m => m.AnimalName).Contains(a.Name)).ToList();
```

This will return a `List<Animal>` object containing the animals that the `Name` matches the `AnimalName` from the list of butchering memos. Then you won't need your `List<string> animalNamesInButchering` because it's found in the statement.

Comment: `animalsToButcher` might be the single most metal variable name ever.

Comment: @Dortimer this question is a bit brutal :'(

Comment: I like that it returns List<Animal> over a generic list! Thank you!

Comment: @Sly-Merc That's what you asked for! Glad it works for you. As mentioned in a different answer, if you need to make animal names regardless of case, you can make `m.AnimalName` and `a.Name` both `.ToLower()` and then all cases would get matched. Right now, only exact matches would be returned.

Answer (score 2):

You essentially want to get all such animals whose name is present in `ButcheringMemo` list. You can use Linq `Join()` like below (`System.Linq` namespace)

```
var data = butcheringMemos.Join(animals,
                                x => x.AnimalName,
                                y => y.Name,
                                (x, y) => new { Animal = x}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a slightly different Linq syntax that does a case-insensitive comparison of the animal name:

```
private static List<Animal> GetAnimalsToButcher()
{
    List<ButcheringMemo> butcheringMemos = getAllButcheringMemos();

    return getAllAnimals()
        .Where(animal => butcheringMemos.Any(memo =>
            memo.AnimalName.Equals(animal.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        .ToList();
}
```